# Can't drop columns or slice dataframe using dask?

Tags: dask

I am trying to use dask instead of pandas since I have 2.6gb csv file. 
I load it and I want to drop a column. but it seems that neither the drop method 
df.drop('column') or slicing df[ : , :-1]

is implemented yet.   Is this the case or am I just missing something ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We implemented the `drop` method in [this PR](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/dask/pull/546).  This is available as of dask 0.7.0.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 2, 1]})

In [3]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [4]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [5]: ddf.drop('y', axis=1).compute()
Out[5]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Previously one could also have used slicing with column names; though of course this can be less attractive if you have many columns.

```
In [6]: ddf[['x']].compute()
Out[6]: 
   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: Why ".compute()"? If your database is very large, doesn't this slow you down??

Comment: I only use compute above to show results of the computation.  You're correct that calling compute prematurely can be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
print(ddf.shape)
ddf = ddf.drop(columns, axis=1)
print(ddf.shape)
```